# Galois group of $X^4 + 20 ∈ ℚ[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I believe this one hasn't been answered yet. To me, it's a tough one.

Let $f := X^4 + 20 ∈ {\Bbb Q}[X]$, $L := Ω^f_{\Bbb Q}$.

Now $f$ factors over $\Bbb C$ as

$$ f = (X + \sqrt[4]{-20})(X - \sqrt[4]{-20})(X + i\sqrt[4]{-20})(X - i\sqrt[4]{-20}).$$

At first I thought that gave splitting field of degree 16 over ${\Bbb Q}$, but it must also be the order of a subgroup of $S_4$, so its degree must divide 24, which 16 does not do.

Once I know the correct splitting field, I would just like a hint for constructing the Galois group at first, instead of a full answer.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The splitting field is clearly generated by a root $\alpha$ of $f$ and $i$, so it has degree at most $8$ and in fact exactly $8$. You were probably thinking that $i$, a primitive $4$th root of unity has degree $4$, but it has degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$. The Galois group should be $D_8$. I might be wrong about the degrees, though, as occasionally funny things happen with $4$.

Comment: Let $j=e^{\pi i/4}$ be a primitive eighth root of unity. Then the roots of $f$ are $j^m\root4\of{20}$, $m=1,3,5,7$.

Answer (score 2):

There is complex conjugation and an obvious 4-cycle (which is reversed by conjugation) so the Galois group will be $D_8$.